# How to omit apps from external drives in "Open With" menu?

Tags: finder, superduper

I maintain a [SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/) clone of my primary boot drive for backup purposes. When it's mounted, Finder's "Open With" menu shows duplicate applications. When I unmount it, they go away.

How do I configure OS X not to show applications from external drives in "Open With"?

[image]

Note: there is [a related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10523/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-open-with-context-menu-items-in-finder-app) involving duplicate "Open With" items. However, it's not related to external backup drives and its answer -- rebuilding the LaunchServices database -- does not solve my problem.

Comment: Just eject it. And leave it unmounted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can prevent the applications on your external drive from appearing in the Open With… menu by preventing Spotlight from indexing the drive.

To do this navigate to **System Preferences > Spotlight**. Select the **Privacy** tab and add your external drive to the list. *Mutineer in the screenshot below is my SuperDuper clone drive.*

[image]

Update:
My best recollection is that this was all I did to solve the problem, but if the problem persists, [two additional steps](https://superuser.com/a/349054) may be necessary:

> **Make Launch Services reload the list of available apps** with the command /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -all local,system,user. As apps on the second drive are not available via Spotlight anymore, the new database will only contain those on your main drive.
>
> **Restart Finder** to rebuild its Open With context menu (Option-right click on its Dock icon to get the restart option, or do killall Finder in Terminal).

*Credit to* [@kopischke](https://superuser.com/users/101110/kopischke) for providing this concise answer on SuperUser.

If you want to avoid the terminal incantations, you can use [Onyx](http://www.onyxmac.com/) to rebuild the spotlight index and launch services database.

Comment: This does not work for me. Actually, I opened Spotlight preferences to find that my clone drive had *already* been added to this list. I guess I had tried this technique before at some point.

Comment: In that case you may also need to [refresh the Spotlight index](http://superuser.com/q/348930) too.

Comment: …and I've expanded my answer to include the additional steps. I don't recall doing this, but I originally faced the issue years ago and I most likely automatically applied the "shortcut solution" when I replaced my clone drive. Apologies.

Comment: but then "find" (files and folders) feature won't work on that external drive :(

Comment: Thanks for this! I have a Boot Camp partition, and kept getting Windows apps showing in the "Open With" menu. The partition kept disappearing from the privacy tab, so I added the WINDOWS folder and the Program Files folder instead - worked like a charm!

Comment: Problem does not resolve the main issue here.