# "Open with" in Finder.app gives duplicate entries

Tags: finder, command-line, filesystem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to omit apps from external drives in “Open With” menu?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39912/how-to-omit-apps-from-external-drives-in-open-with-menu)

in finder's open with menu are a lot of dups. I am running latest OX X and patches.

[image: see screenshot]

I googled and found this command, which didn't help

```
sudo /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

Comment: Related questions: [9929](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9929/) [10523](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10523/) [64124](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64124/) [64580](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64580/) [68596](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68596)