# Why does finder report my applications are in the trash when I use Open With?

Tags: finder, macos, applications

When I attempt to open a a file with Preview (and some other applications) via the **Open With** open I get the following error:

[image: You can't open the application "Preview" because it's in the Trash.]

> You can't open the application "Preview" because it's in the Trash. To
>   open this application, move it from the Trash.

If I open Preview from the applications menu or Spotlight it opens fine.

This may be related, but there are some duplicate applications in my Open With menu, and some that I have deleted. How do I manage these?

Comment: The issue where there's multiple applications is sometimes solved by [rebuilding the Launch Services database](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071102084155353). See [How do I remove duplicate "Open With" context menu items in Finder.app?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10523/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-open-with-context-menu-items-in-finder-app).

Answer (score 3):

As [Lri](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/3936/lri) suggested in a comment, [rebuilding my Launch Services](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071102084155353) seems to have fixed the issue.

To rebuild launch services run the following from a Terminal:

```
 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

Took just a second and cleaned up the duplicates too.

Comment: Multiple file types would not open when double clicked including .tiff, .xls, and .doc. OS is Mountain Lion, creative cloud and 2008 Office. The above line in Terminal took just over a minute to run. A .tiff file opened up photoshopCC when double clicked. Thank you!