# How do I fix duplicate 'Open with...' options?

Tags: macos, applications, shortcut-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I modify the list of Applications under 'Open With…'?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64124/how-can-i-modify-the-list-of-applications-under-open-with)

OS X > 10.8

When right click a file, select 'Open With', some applications are duplicate.

See screenshot below:

[image]

How may I fix it?