# How can I open something in Mac with same Application every time

Tags: mac, application-switcher, open-directory

I want to play videos always by VLC or GOM player but when I chose Open with-other-then I chose the App and I check for "always open with" = it does work but not all the movie in same extention  will work!! I need all the time do the same cyrcl agian and agian?? the same thing with Picturs I don't like the default app"Preview" and I want to use XEE with same way but when I restart my mac I see Everything back to default.

Comment: You might need to perform some more troubleshooting. The steps you describe should work to set the document type and launch services database. If you use tools like Onyx or clear caches, they might be messing up the integrity of the system. If not, you might need to reset the caches / launch services database. Why not try resetting things with this Q&A - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64124/how-can-i-modify-the-list-of-applications-under-open-with

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl click or Right click on the item then select Get Info from the popup menu (or else select the item and select Get Info from the File Menu). When Get Info window is open you can select what app to open it with and choose to open all similiar documents with the new app as well.

Comment: in the get info window you can set the VLC s default application for all your video files. Just make sure you open the right file type, video or pic, than select your preferred application to use, and set it as default application.

Answer (score -3):

Go to this link . It solves the problem .
http://www.photoshopessentials.com/essentials/default-image-editor-mac/

Comment: Could you explain what the solution is not just provide a link

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.