# How to remove applications in virtual machine (via VMWare Fusion 5) from Open With options on Mac OS X

Tags: vmware

I'm running Windows 8 on a Mac using VMware Fusion 5. I don't want to see the Windows apps in the Finder's "Open With..." options. 
I have seen other answers that do not work with this version of VMware.

Things that I've tried.

1. Delete the applications folder from each VM package
2. Uncheck the applications option in the Virtual Machine -> Settings.

Comment: To avoid getting the same answers again, can you please add (or link to) the things you've already tried?

Comment: I suspect that you need to rebuild the 'Launch Services Database', but I don't currently have Fusion to test. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/64124/1346