# How do I reorder the programs in the 'open with' window of a file?

Tags: macos, finder, launch-services

I want to reorder (not change the default program) the programs suggested in the menu when I click on 'open with' for a file.

I don’t want to [add or remove programs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64124/how-can-i-modify-the-list-of-applications-under-open-with), just sort them for easier selection.

Is this possible natively or with another program or launcher?

Comment: [How can I modify the list of Applications under 'Open With…'?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64124/how-can-i-modify-the-list-of-applications-under-open-with)

Comment: @ankii: That question deals with the old duplication bug from a few years back. It doesn't address how to change the order of existing items in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Unless someone comes up with some heavy magic, I'm going to say: "No". Apple lists the apps that can open that file type in alphabetical order. (Higher versions of the same app are listed first.)

The practical ways around this are removing apps or changing them when they offer to open a type you don’t want or establishing drop folders that open dropped documents in the app of your choosing when sending a document to the non-preferred app.

For example, [LaunchBar app has a send to feature](https://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/features.html) that lets you send a file to any app quickly with a couple key strokes, which does take setup and training.

Answer (score 2):

Since the programmes are presented in alphabetical order, you can just rename them or preface them with a numerical or alphabetic identifier. I have Lightroom CC as part of the Adobe suite. I think I must have added it by mistake and it now precedes Photoshop. So I kept on clicking on it by mistake, instead of Photoshop. I never use Lightroom CC as use the classic version, but I want to check it out, so don’t want to delete it yet. So I just prefaced the programme name with a Z and now it shows at the bottom of the list. Clumsy solution. Not sure if I’d choose it for a program I use regularly but works for me on this.

Comment: Elegant way to dismiss the top result. I see this often in folder naming conventions. Z_another_folder and ZZ_a_folder