Many versions of same app under "Open With" in Finder context menu
When I right-click certain files in the find and hover over Open With, the submenu that appears with suggested applications contains many versions of several applications. How can I remove these extraneous menu options?


I think this answer would work. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64124/how-can-i-modify-the-list-of-applications-under-open-with

I really wish there was a solution that prevented it from happening in the first place rather than cleaning it up after the fact. Feels like putting a band-aid on the problem.
