# How would I troubleshoot generic icons for apps showing in a third party app?

Tags: macos, finder, applications, icon

I use LaunchBar and it sometimes loses the custom icon. I have asked the vendor for support and will answer should I get an answer, but I wondered if I could find a cause or fix for missing icon previews on the OS level.

[image]

What's super odd is that Finder and the macOS app switcher show the correct icons - just LaunchBar 6 Version 6.9.4 seems to be dropping the icons. I'm seeing this on 10.12.6 and 10.13.x and the issue persists after a reboot.

Is there an icon services API or subsystem that could need rebuilding or is this just a third party issue where the tool needs a fix or reset?

Answer (score 2):

Well - it turns out LaunchBar was reporting things as they are and Finder and the rest of the systems started dropping the icons to match what this utility was showing.

I have recovered from the failure by rebuilding the launch services database.

The short command is `lsregister -kill -seed` and here's the full path

```
  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -seed
```

This still hasn't figured out why they went wrong, but it's a rebuild step that can be taken once the number of "broken" icons become aggravating. This is very odd to me since the `lsregister` command used to be vey handy when [duplicate open as records were present](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10523/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-open-with-context-menu-items-in-finder-app), but I didn't have that symptom here. Also, typically cleaning icon caches in `/var/folders` and then performing a safe boot. That's not something I ever liked contemplating and was very happy to not have to resort to trying that in this case.

Comment: This is not a permanent solution, I'm seeing icons go missing in Finder app switching and list view (small mini icons) on almost a daily basis. Something is clearly up, and I will edit / update this answer as i discover what version or update has fix as opposed to just recovering / rebuilding the database on a daily basis.